# Выполнение Javascript анимации в Java (Android Studio)

Tags: javascript, android, android-studio

Я пытаюсь написать игру на андроид, и вот, перед началом игры у меня должна проигрываться анимация (типо мини-мультфильм) после чего пользователь начинает играть. Как можно запустить ее (она реализована с помощью Javascript) ?

Comment: Как вариант проиграть ее в WebView.

Comment: Пытался, она вроде бы работает, но ничего не отображает, белый екран. Могли бы вы привести пример, если не сложно?Спасибо)

Comment: Вот пример: http://dmiter.blogspot.ru/2012/07/javascript-webview.html. А лучше покажите Ваш код, чтобы понять в чем причина

Comment: Спасибо, попробую этим спомобом, если не получиться, то кину код сюда.